# Can't seem to figure out how to index PDF files using a Solr Container in Docker

Tags: docker, indexing, solr

I'm pretty new to using Docker and Solr.

I have a file full of PDFs that I want to index but I can't seem to find any advice on how to index PDFs, Word Files, etc, on a Solr container in Docker.

Can anyone give me any advice?

I followed [this tutorial](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/deployment-guide/solr-in-docker.html) from Solr on how to index a Spread Sheet, however the file used in the tutorial was already in CVS.

I've scoured the internet for hours and I cant find any tutorials for indexing PDFs in Solr Docker.

Comment: Which part of the tutorial is the one you're having trouble with? There is nothing different with sending files for indexing to Solr when running under Docker compared to when running standalone, so the reference guide for indexing rich content should be a good starting point: https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/indexing-guide/indexing-with-tika.html